# How do I turn an IObservable<IObservable<T>> into an IObservable<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, f#, observable, reactive-programming

Let say I have a function which returns `IObservable<T>` and this function needs initial state.

```
let myObservable (initialState: T) :IObservable<T> = (...)
```

but I can get initial state only from another observable which **emits only once**

```
let initializeObservable: IObservable<S> = (...)
```

how can I combine these two to get `IObservable<T>`?

```
let resultObservable = initializeObservable |>
                       Observable.map (fun initialState -> myObservable initialState)
```

Currently resultObservable is `IObservable<IObservable<T>>` but I would like it to be `IObservable<T>` and emit values from myObservable after initial state is ready.

Answer (score 4):

In general if you take an elevated type `A<T>`, lower it to `T`, project it from `T -> U` and lift it to get `A<U>`, that operation is called `bind`.

```
Observable.bind (fun init -> myObservable init) initializeObservable
```

Or to simplify:

```
initializeObservable |> Observable.bind myObservable
```

---

As for your approach, you're pretty much there.

```
initializeObservable 
|> Observable.map (fun initialState -> myObservable initialState)
|> Observable.mergeInner
```

Even if your `initializeObservable` emits n times, you can just merge all the observables together, which is equally valid even if it emits just once.

Comment: Simply replacing Observable.map with Observable.bind and skipping mergeInner would do it, no?

Comment: Or just initializeObservable |> Observable.bind myObservable

Comment: Yes, of course. But if you had to consume a higher order observable generally, you'd use either `collect`, `merge` or `switch` depending on your use-case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [F# Reactive extensions:](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Control.Reactive/)

```
open FSharp.Control.Reactive.Builders
   
 let result  = 
        observe {
            let! s0 = initializeObservable
            yield! myObservable s0
        }
```